# Change ticks of y-axis in python

Tags: python

I want to change y axis ticks in python. I am using the code

```
import pylab as plt
y1 = [0,1,2,...10]
y2 = [90,40,65,12,....]
labels = [0.30,0.29,0.28,....]
plt.plot(y1)
plt.plot(y2,'r')
plt.yticks(y1, labels)
plt.yticks(y2, labels)
plt.show()
```

But all the y axis label appear at one place on top of one another

Comment: Are you trying to put two plots onto the same figure? As in `labels` against `y1` and `labels` against `y2`?

Comment: Yes. two plots on same figure

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html), the code below demonstrates one possible way to have two plots on one figure.

```
import pylab as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
y1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

labels = [0.30,0.29,0.28,0.27,0.26,0.25,0.24,0.23,0.22,0.21,0.20]
ax1.plot(labels, y1, 'b-')

ax1.set_xlabel('labels')
# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('y1', color='b', rotation="horizontal")
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
y2 = [90,40,65,12,23,43,54,13,42,53,63]
ax2.plot(labels, y2, 'r-')
ax2.set_ylabel('y2', color='r', rotation="horizontal")
ax2.tick_params('y', colors='r')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```